# Como mudar o texto do botão OK do Alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, navegador-de-internet

Pessoal preciso de um Alert com o botão "Confirmar" ao invés de do botão "OK".
como faço isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma opção é usar algum plugin que monte uma janelinha de confirmação customizada. A vantagem é poder estilizar com as cores e o texto que você quiser. A desvantagem é ter que usar mais um plugin no seu código.

Por exemplo, veja a funcionalidade Dialog do jQuery UI:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Considerando que o jQuery UI esteja instalado, o código fica assim:

### Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Remover todos os itens?": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
  });
});
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Todos os itens serão removidos. Deseja continuar?</p>
</div>
```

PS: Se quiser algo mais "moderninho", essa opção é legal também:

http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/

Answer (score 2):

Ao envés de `alert` use a função `confirm`, ela retorna `true` caso o usuário confirme a ação, porém o texto do botão de ambas as funções não pode ser alterado, é relativo ao navegador usado.

Outra possivel solução seria criar um alerta customizado com Javascript e CSS.